# Error in Execution on running linkedin login example for flutter

Tags: flutter, linkedin-api

I tried the linkedin login example,and faced the following error

Android dependency 'androidx.fragment:fragment' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I tried migating the app to android x,but still the error is following.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to android x should do it. 
Check this link for more details https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility and come back with more information, if your problem still occurs.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Answer (score 0):

Try using flutter_linkedin it's easier and having no issues... https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkedin